# Upper bound of sum of sub-tree depth difference on a complete binary tree with $n$ leaves

Tags: trees, binary-trees

A complete binary tree with $n$ leaves has $n-1$ internal nodes. For every internal node $i$, I care about the difference between the maximum depth of the left sub-tree and the maximum depth of the right sub-tree $d_i$.

I'm wondering what's the upper bound for $D = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} d_i$, given $n$ ? The lower bound is almost trivially 0. As when the tree is a balanced tree, all $d_i = 0$.

Comment: create a skewed tree. Then, for that tree $D = \Theta(n^2)$. And, $D$ can never be larger than $n^2$. So the bound is tight.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami You should post that as an answer!

Comment: @Nathaniel I will write an answer as soon as I get time. Or maybe yupbank can write it.